# Reducing complexity of following code

Tags: python

What I wanted to do was to search in a list and remove a value .

So I wrote the following code

```
for x in range(10):
   if x in list1:
      list1.remove(x)
```

Does this function of order ~ (n^2) since first it looks for the value and then it deletes and pushes the rest of the values backwards ??

Also is there a way to turn this in order n by using try/except

```
try:
  for x in range(10):
    list1.remove(x)
except ValueError:
  # make it go back to next iteration
```

Comment: In the second case, why not try/except IN the for loop?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you'd better not use a built-in name for a variable name. Python lets you do this, but it could have unintended consequences if you don't know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @Tim: Very true, although it could be worse (with dynamic scoping - eeeevil) ;)

Comment: In Python `^` is the bitwise exclusive or operator, which means being "order ~ (n^2)" isn't all that bad. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter):

```
>>> filter(lambda x: not x in (4, 5, 7), xrange(10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9]
```

**Update**: one more example where I construct a list using [*list comprehension*](http://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html):

```
>>> filter(lambda x: not x[0] in (4, 5, 7), [[a] for a in xrange(10)])
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [6], [8], [9]]
```

Comment: hey , what about if my x is in a nested list like a = [[1],[2],[2]] and I want to do the same ie calculate all those values of LIST not in a , would writing a in place of xrange work ??

Comment: This creates a new list but is stil checking each element in an existing one (or an iterator in the examples) against each element in another sequence of those to remove. It might be a little faster than a `for` because it uses `filter()`, but it's probably not all that much more efficient.

Comment: I am utterly aware of it's properties, after all the latter one is just one more example.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
L = [x for x in L if x not in removal_list]
```

removal_list can be any container, but if you use a set() or a frozenset() you will achieve O(n) (with n = len(L)).

Comment: +1 but `/(.*) removal_list\\]/removal_set = set\\(removal_list\\)\n\1 removal_set\\]/`. Why wouldn't you want to get from `O(n**2)` to `O(n)` with such a simple change?

Comment: `L = [x for in x in L if x not in removal_list]` is invalid syntax.

Comment: @user506710: The beginning `[x for in x in L...` part is syntactically incorrect and couldn't possibly work. Making it `[x for x in L...`. is and does. It's probably just a typo indicating that it was never tested before being posted (likely because it seemed so trivial to the author). I'm glad that apparently didn't trip you up, but that doesn't seem to be the case with others since it got up-voting so much (which my motivation for pointing the problem out after I verified it was wrong).

Comment: Typo fixed. I obviosuly *not* tested it because it is 101 python syntax, I do trust myself more than this :) Typos just happen, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Slice replacement:

```
a[:] = ( l for l in a if l not in set(list_of_removable))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pythons not my area, but some things spring to mind. First, how big is the list, because you are going to iterate over it a number of times. If it's large it might be a better idea to flip things around so you only iterate over it once.

Second, if Python is like Java, then there is a rule for good code - Do not use exceptions for process flow. This rules out your second suggestion. It's also likely that it will perform badly.

Comment: @Derek: in Python, the maxim is "better to ask forgiveness than permission". The second example (with the `try` inside the loop) is reasonable Python style and would be fairly efficient.

Comment: @Derek could you please clarify "Do not use exceptions for process flow" for Java? Why?

Comment: It won't be efficient (or recommended) if you're expecting an exception most of the time. (But even though your advice turns out okay here, I don't recommend answering Python questions if you're a Java guy ;) )

Comment: @delnan Completely unrelated but I have created a list of 10 numbers say main_list and whenever one of these numbers come I delete it from main_list if it exists in it, so that I get all the non occurring ones in main_list. So I would expect that these exceptions occur a lot of time . So I should'nt use try except in this ???

Comment: @user506710: he's speaking as a Java developer. What would in this case be bad for Java is not in Python because Python is Cooler than Java. ;-)

Comment: @user506710: If your list only has 10 or so numbers in it, unless you're going to remove things from it millions of times in some spped critical portion of your code, it just doesn't really matter how you do it because you'll never be able to tell the difference.

Comment: Hi everyone, yes I'm talking as a Java developer :-) The reason I suggested that it might perform badly using the try was that in Java, setting up a try catch block is expensive. So doing it is to be avoided unless you are really trying to catch an exception. Especially avoided if within a loop. The comment about avoid exceptions for process flow is both a performance one in Java and also a practice one. Exception should be kept for exceptional situations. Using them for process flow can cause developer confusion and risk introducing bugs. At least in the java world :-)

Answer (score 0):

Like Giovanni Bajo suggests, list comprehension is cool, but assuming you'll use the result only once, generators are even better:

```
l = [1,23,2,24,3,26,1]
(x for x in l if x not in xrange(10))
```

`xrange()` is a generator as well and is faster than `range()`
If you want to use the result more than once I'd go for:

```
[x for x in l if x not in xrange(10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question: There is no getting around the fact that you will have to compare each element of the list-to-remove-elements-from to each element of the list-containing-removable-elements. So in that sense, every version of this code is O(N^2) (assuming we can have arbitrarily many elements in each list). You can hide the loops by using a variety of constructs (and in many cases it will be faster, because the looping can be done "internally" in the C code of the interpreter rather than by interpreting more bytecode), but the loops are still there (and remember that constant factors are ignored by big-O analysis).